# 2nd Headphone Jack Isn't Working on my Toshiba Laptop

Tags: toshiba-laptop, headphones, headphone-jack

So, I have a Toshiba Laptop, and it has two headphone jacks. The first one was working fine, but the second one, when I try to play any sound, the sound comes out of the laptop, and not through my headphones. Last week, my nephew broke the working jack. Does anyone have any idea how to get sound through the second headphone jack? I have tried going into the control panel, going into hardware and sound, sound, and putting in my headphones. I've read that a headphone icon should pop up, but it doesn't. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the microphone jack?

Comment: @Peter is right. Audio jacks are usually green, while microphone jacks are usually red. You may be mistaking the microphone jack as a second jack for your headphones.

Comment: Neither of the jacks have a colour, they are just black. I used to have a pair of headphones that had two, whatchamacallits... erm.... the metal rod type things that you put into the jacks (Sorry, im not that much of a computer genius...). It might be a microphone jack, as I said, im not a computer genius. Ive read that you can still get sound through headphones if you put them in the that jack though? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any Toshiba Notebook with two headphone jack.
The second jack is a Microphone jack!

There are some Toshiba notebooks which have a combined headphone/microphone jack, but they only have one jack.
Those with two jacks have separated jacks for microphone and headphone.

Comment: Oh okay, I've read you can still get sound through headphones if you put them in the 2nd jack though? Am I wrong?

Comment: I think so. Which device do you have exactly?

Comment: Toshiba Satellite c855

Comment: According to the descriptions in the user's guide (pages 2-3 and 2-4), there is a headphones-only and a microphone-only jack. No headphones function via the mic jack.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers your question, please mark the answer as the correct answer so that others can also make use of it.